# ¿Crear variables en Razor para luego manipularlas en Jquery?

Tags: jquery, mvc, razor

¿Es posible hacer algo como esto?:

```
@{var list = [1,2,3,4,5]; }
```

No me bota error pero luego cuando quiero utilizar esa variable en Jquery, no aparece.

¿Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible recorriendo la lista en el array de javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var list = [1,2,3,4,5];

    @foreach (var d in list)
    {
        @:myArray.push("@d");
    }

    alert(myArray);

</script>
```